# How can I upgrade my Laptop Asus X553 MA Pentium Quad-Core N3540 2.16 GHz ~ 2.66 GHz Processor

Tags: processor

I am a .NET developer and need to work with Visual Studio 2015, SQL server etc.

I am ready to spend INR 6000 K(100 US $).

Details below:

Laptop : Asus X 553 MA 
Processor : Pentium® Quad-Core N3540 2.16 GHz ~ 2.66 GHz Processor
RAM: DDR3 1600 MHz SDRAM, 2 GB 
Graphics: Integrated Intel® HD Graphics (Pentium & Celeron)
2.5" SATA
 - 500GB HDD 5400 RPM

https://www.asus.com/in/Laptops/X553MA/specifications/

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt, investing in a Solid-State hard drive is the best option to extend the life and performance of your laptop. With $100 to play with, you'll be able to afford an SSD with around 240GB of storage which should be plenty of space to install your software/OS and store your files that you work on most often.

I would recommend you have a professional do the installation and Operating system/data migration for you if your technical proficiency does not

Comment: Thanks, what about the RAM upgrade ?
also I am a software developer so I can do the backup etc.